# What is this BUD folder?

Tags: files

I noticed a folder named "BUD" on the SD card of my Android 4 phone, containing 5 10-byte files with .med2.gz extensions. The .med2 files are empty. What is this clutter? [This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/xda-assist/bud-files-t3385914) [thread](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/bug-folder.69541/) didn't help, nor did Google know what a .med2 file is.

[image: Mysterious BUD folder with med2.gz files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting all files by their modified date, i noticed the mystery file dates match with those of the Navfree app i used at that time. So aside from being slower than its previous version, it also litters temp files all over my card.

[image: Navfree clutter]